# Error when trying to extend a db_select query

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to add a field to my query by using addField(). However, whenever I add this to the query I get a whitescreen and an apache error message on the line after. Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

Apache error log:

`PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object`

db_select query:

```
$query = db_select('z_revision', 't')
    ->fields('t', array('drupal_user_id'))
    ->addField('t', 'z', 'category')
    ->extend('PagerDefault') # error on this line
    ->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header)
    ->limit(30)
    ->execute();
```

Ideally this would give me a two column table with headers 'drupal_user_id' and 'category' - all the rows in the category column having 'z' as a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addField` returns the alias of the field that's added, not the query object. You just need to break your code up a bit:

```
$query = db_select('z_revision', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('drupal_user_id'));

$query->addField('t', 'z', 'category');

$result = $query->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->extend('TableSort')
  ->orderByHeader($header)
  ->limit(30)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Clive. That cleared the error but now I get a new one. Is addField() the best way to create a totally new arbirary field in my query results? I'm getting a `Column not found in field list` error now. Hoping to do something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769702/how-to-create-a-new-column-in-a-select-query

Comment: The easiest way to debug is to cast the query object to a string before you execute it - that's give you the raw SQL, should make it a lot easier to spot what's going wrong. It's difficult to guess what you're looking for without knowing the structure of the tables

Comment: Thanks Clive - I managed add a column on the fly using addExpression() https://api.drupal.org/comment/33553#comment-33553